# Is there an Android PMP equivalent of the iPod Touch?

Tags: mp3, pmp, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any devices that are like an iPod Touch, but run Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/967/are-there-any-devices-that-are-like-an-ipod-touch-but-run-android)

In other words, is there a piece of dedicated hardware designed (or shipped with) Android that is meant as a media player, so that I wouldn't have to pay for a phone, and just not use the phone features?

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/967/are-there-any-devices-that-are-like-an-ipod-touch-but-run-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also the [Archos 28](http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_28it/index.html?country=gb&lang=en) which is a little smaller and a little cheaper than the [Archos 32](http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_32it/index.html?country=gb&lang=en).  Again, they're both referred to as tablets but the Archos site (links previously) both say "Excellent multimedia player".

Also, [MP4Nation](http://www.mp4nation.net/catalog/) may have some Android PMPs.

Comment: All of these are good answers, and all are linked equally. Yours is the closest to an answer I originally envisioned, with better info than my own answer [!!!].

Comment: I am now using an Orange San Francisco handset (rebadged ZTE Blade), sans sim card, debranded, flashed with FroYo (Android 2.2) and loaded with some well chosen apps as my day-to-day media player.  A review of the San Francisco/Blade can be found at:  http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/10/28/zte-blade-orange-san-francisco-review-two-thirds-of-a-nexus-one-for-one-third-the-price/

Answer (score 2):

The Barnes & Noble Nook is based on Android, has no monthly fees, and includes the ability to playback music.  It probably isn't what you have in mind as a media player, but I think it fits your description.

Comment: I keep forgetting about the Nook.

Comment: also; seems that nook has been rooted http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2009/12/nook-torn-open-hacked-and-rooted/

Answer (score 1):

The [Archos 32](http://www.talkandroid.com/14183-archos-32-pmp-pretends-to-be-an-android-tablet) sounds like it's the closest, so far. Although it is bizarrely referred to as a tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung has a [Galaxy Player 50 PMP](http://phandroid.com/2010/09/02/samsung-shows-off-galaxy-player-50-pmp-not-the-yp-mb2-at-ifa/), which will be coming out soon.