# Are there any devices that are like an iPod Touch, but run Android?

Tags: pmp

A lot of people like iPod Touches because they're almost identical to iPhones, but without cell service (and the monthly fees that go along with it), while still being able to connect to a wireless network. Are there any alternative devices that run Android?

Bonus points if it has at least 24 GB of storage.

Comment: see also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/152/is-there-an-android-pmp-equivalent-of-the-ipod-touch (this question was asked on and migrated from gadgets.SE prior to the start of AE)

Answer (score 5):

Nothing of quality yet (at least IMO).  Archos has just announced a new product line of Android tablets and smaller devices.  Also Samsung has announced the Galaxy tablet (http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-20015395-1.html) that looks impressive.

I think you'll have a ton of options around the Christmas shopping season.. Keep an eye on Engadget, not a day goes by they're not showing another "leaked" Android tablet.

ETA:
here's a link to the Archos 101 tablet.. Looks pretty impressive:
http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_101it/index.html?country=us&lang=en

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly the sort of thing that I'm looking for. Unfortunately the Archos 4.3 (the highest capacity pocket-sized Archos tablet), which isn't even out yet, has a max capacity of 16GB. But I'm sure it's only a matter of time before it hits 32GB. Thanks!

Comment: Also: I realize that there is a micro-sd slot available on it. I have one on my Sansa Clip+, but having the available space split in 2 means I can't automatically sync it with Banshee. I have to manage it manually.

Comment: Funny, lets see if the price is going to be worth it, because if it is the same price as the iPad it will be a hard sale (except you can add more storage vs having to buy a new iPad)

Comment: @Dmitriy Likhten The prices are roughly half of Apple for many of the Archos products. http://archos.com/

Answer (score 4):

The recently announced [Samsung Galaxy Player SD](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/bbs/stars.ThreadBoard.do?starMbrId=SteveHa&viewType=rss&messageId=96626) is Samsung's go at an Android based PMP (Personal Media Player) in a similar vein to the iPod Touch.

It has Wifi connectivity and no phone voice or data capability built-in, but other than that, [from the recently released offcial video](http://www.samsunghub.com/2010/10/20/video-samsung-galaxy-player-yp-g50-ad/), it appears to be running exactly the same software with the same Samsung apps and Samsung TouchWiz interface add-ons as the full Galaxy S, albeit in a smaller form factor with a lower spec camera.

Comment: Wow, what an anemic device.  Why couldn't they just release a Galaxy S without a cellular radio?

Comment: @Matt presumably from the "Player SD" name, there's going to be a "Player HD" model announced in a while...

Answer (score 3):

Just buy an Android phone. The newer ones are supporting 32gb of storage. You don't have to activate the phone if you don't want to and you will get all the functionality. Or just upgrade to an Android phone and then have the best of both worlds. The way Android handles music works beautifully.

Comment: The problem is that most Android phones seem to be in the ~$500-600 range without a contract. I'm looking for something closer to ~$200-300.

Comment: You're not looking in the right places. Ebay has a TON of Android phones for sub $300. Just type in "Android cell phone" and search. Then scroll down and on the left side type in your price range. There are new Samsung Galaxy S phones going for just under $350 if you can spend it. I would get one of those for sure. Point being if you look hard enough you can find them.

Comment: Disagree that android handles music well.  Which app are you using?  The native music app is very poor quality compared to iPod touch.

Comment: You can purchase a G1 for about ~$100 on ebay.  See my answer here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2182/cheapest-android-to-buy-on-line-south-europe/2185#2185

Comment: Have you tried [dx.com](http://www.dx.com/) shop? They have Android-based devices for even below $100. True, these are Chinese craps, but should be great for just an audio player.

Answer (score 3):

I own an [Archos 43](http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_43it/index.html?country=us&lang=en) (16GB internal with an microSD card slot), and I really like it.  Keep in mind with the Generation 8 Archos tablets (Archos 28, Archos 32, Archos 43, Archos 70, and Archos 101), only the Archos 70 and Archos 101 have capacitive touchscreens, so they are the only multi-touch capable devices in the product line.

UPDATE:

Since posting my answer, some new products have been announced.  Check out the [Amazon Kindle Fire](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0051VVOB2) and [Samsung Galaxy Player 50](http://www.samsung.com/galaxyplayer50/), although both of those are larger than an iPod Touch.

Also, Archos has announced some new [ninth generation tablets](http://www.archos.com/products/gen9/index.html?country=us&lang=en), the Archos 80 G9 and the Archos 101 G9.

Answer (score 2):

As Don says, Archos are releasing a range of "tablets" (most are really PMPs, like the iPod touch) during September and October.

The register have a good breakdown of the full range here: http://www.reghardware.com/2010/09/01/archos_android_tablets/

Answer (score 1):

The Archos tablets have not generally received good reviews to this point.  The Dell Streak has also received bad reviews.  Further, Google has said the current version of Android is not optimized for tablets.  I would personally wait for Android 3.  By then, the first gen tablets will be passed and the lessons learned will drive a much better second generation of tablets with an Android OS designed for them.